# how to call the functions that are object members?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have want to call the function that is a object attribute. For example consider the code

```
var obj={
  a:"One",
  b:"two",
  c:'three',
  d:function f(){
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
}
```

I want to call the function f. How would I do that?
I tried to google, but I am unable to find it anywhere, Maybe I am phrasing the question wrong wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an example

```
var fun=function(){
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

We can call the function by `fun()`
In Your example

```
var obj={
  a:"One",
  b:"two",
  c:'three',
  d:function f(){
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
}
```

You can use d() to call the function. But since it is a member of the object obj. We can only access it by referring to obj. So we could use

```
obj.d()
```

or

```
(obj.d)()
```

Alternatively you could assign it to another variable.

```
var fu=obj.d;
fu();
```

Comment: Note that the code does not cause a syntax error because it is a specific syntax in js: named function expressions. The name `f` is valid only inside `obj.d` and can simply be called using `f()`. It is a local variable and does not exist outside the function. This syntax was created to allow anonymous functions to implement recursion because arguments.callee was in the process of being deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Just call the key which holds the function.

`obj.d();`

```js
var obj = {
  a: "One",
  b: "two",
  c: 'three',
  d: function f() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
}

obj.d();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get any value from object using `.(dot)` notation. since d has function f you call using `obj.d()`

```js
var obj={
  a:"One",
  b:"two",
  c:'three',
  d:function f(){
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
}

obj.d();
```